dynamodb get specific item
% aws dynamodb scan --table-name signer                                     
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "image": {
                "S": "akar"
            },
            "arn": {
                "S": "abc"
            }
        },
        {
            "image": {
                "S": "pdns"
            },
            "arn": {
                "S": "cde"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}

I'm trying to the specific value "abc" I tried the following but it complains about schema not correct
% aws dynamodb get-item --table-name signer --key '{"Items": {"S": "akar"}}'
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
What is the correct cli for me to get abc?
% aws dynamodb get-item --table-name signer --key '{"Items": {"S": "akar"}}'
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
What is the correct cli for me to get abc?

Assuming that arn is your partition key and you have no sort key on your table your GetItem should look like this:
aws dynamodb get-item \
--table-name signer \
--key '{"arn":{"S":"abc"}}'

Replace the values for whichever is the partition key for your table. If you have a sort key you must add that too.
